# Tcl split by tabs (\t)

Tags: tcl

I am trying to split a Tcl string by TABS (\t).

Please consider the following `sampleString`:

```
I . am -> a . programmer # let "." be spaces and "->" be tabs
```

If I try to do the following:

```
set myVar [split $sampleString "\t"]
```

Tcl will split by spaces as well and not just the tabs.

How can I split only by tabs?

Thanks

Comment: that's some wierd behaviour...

Comment: Just tested it myself, and it works fine for me. Have you simplified your problem for the question? If so, you might want to post more of your original problem, because the issue is elsewhere...

Comment: `% set sampleString {I    am -> a         programmer}` outputs `I        am -> a         programmer`. Then, `% set myVar [split $sampleString "\t"]` outputs `{I } { am -> a } { programmer}`.

Comment: Perhaps, you can post your snippet so others can help. I tried what you suggested and found the string was splited correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're just a little confused as to which output you are looking at.

```
% set s "I am\ta programmer"
I am    a programmer
% split $s
I am a programmer
% split $s "\t"
{I am} {a programmer}
```

The only difference between the two `split`s is that without the optional second argument, the split-set is “all whitespace” (for a reasonable definition of “all”), and neither `split` affects the value in the variable as there is no explicit write-back here.